# Force-carrying particles instead of forces

Tags: forces, interactions, carrier-particles

Are there physical theories in which notions of particle are used without the concept of force?

I know about gauge bosons, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_carrier and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction.

Comment: I reworded your question to hopefully make it more clear; is the question still asking what you want?

Comment: Actually, Richard Feynman launched his career and eventually developed his version of QED based on his assumption (a hope, really) that particles interacted directly. To Feynman, fields were just a manifestation of how that direct particle-to-particle interaction operates.

Comment: BMS, exactly that. I like your revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantum field theories have no *direct notion* of force, neither in the "physical approach" through a Lagrangian and the [path integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation), nor in the "mathematical approach" through [Wightman](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Wightman+axioms), [Haag-Kastler](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Haag-Kastler+axioms) or other axioms.

The theory of "force carriers" is developed without ever appealing to forces - one imposes a local gauge symmetry upon the theory and discovers that a new notion of derivative is needed, leading in turn to the introduction of a new field, the gauge field, whose quanta are the gauge bosons. From this theory you may obtain the classical notion of force through the non-relativistic limit of the tree-level Feynman diagram between two particles charged under that symmetry.<sup>1</sup> But that is not the whole story - the interaction between the gauge field and the matter fields is far more than just that one diagram, more than just that force.

Also, note that *particles* are not the fundamental notion of QFTs - they are certain excitations of the fields, and it is possible to have field excitations that are relevant that are not particles, e.g. [instantons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Of course, we are interested in such quantum gauge theories because we know they lead to classical forces, but nothing in their quantum description is dependent on that notion.</sup>